# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final transient java.net.InetSocketAddress

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to delete elastic documents in bulk amount, but I get exception `"java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final transient java.net.InetSocketAddress"` when `elasticsearchOperations.delete(...)` is executed. Here is the code, not able to figure out what is causing it. Any help is much appreciated.

```
private void deleteElasticDocuments(String catalogId) {
    List<String> docIdList = new ArrayList<>(250);
    String queryText = martServerContext.getQueryCacheInstance().getQuery(QUERY_PORTAL_GET_OBJECTS_IN_PORTAL_BY_MODEL);
    MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("cId", Integer.parseInt(catalogId));
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(queryText, mapSqlParameterSource, (resultSet -> {
        int objectId = resultSet.getInt(O_ID);
        String docId = catalogId + objectId;
        docIdList.add(docId);
        if (docIdList.size() == 250) {
            Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                    .withQuery(QueryBuilders.idsQuery().addIds(docIdList.toArray(String[]::new)))
                    .build();
            elasticsearchOperations.delete(query, IndexCoordinates.of("portal_idx"));
            docIdList.clear();
        }
        // elasticsearchOperations.delete(docId, IndexCoordinates.of("portal_idx"));
    }));
    if (docIdList.size() < 250) {
        Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(QueryBuilders.idsQuery().addIds(docIdList.toArray(String[]::new)))
                .build();
        elasticsearchOperations.delete(query, IndexCoordinates.of("portal_idx"));
        docIdList.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with query and index, I added my Class `MetadataSearch.class` and now it is working.

```
elasticsearchOperations.delete(query, MetadataSearch.class, IndexCoordinates.of("portal_idx"));
```

**Edit (by P.J.Meisch):**

Let me explain why you got this error. You were calling the function with the signature

```
ElasticsearchOperations.delete(Object, IndexCoordinates)
```

Here ElasticsearchOperations takes the first parameter as an entity object which should be deleted and tries to find its id-property. Normally you'd pass in an instance of `MetadataSearch` in your case. Spring Data Elasticsearch already would know what properties this object has from the initial setup.

But now it gets an object that is a `NativeSearchQuery` and which is not known as an entity type and so Spring Data Elasticsearch analyses the object and its properties and this goes down to properties of the properties ...

`NativeSearchQuery` has a property of type `RequestBuilder`, this has a `SearchRequest` which in turn contains a `TransportAddress` and this has an `InetSocketAddress`. And here the inspection fails with the error you see.

So indeed using the `delete` variant taking a query, the entity class and the IndexCoordinates is the right way. If your `MetadataSearch` class is annotated with `@Document(indexName="portal_idx")` you can omit the last parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, yes MetadataSearch class is annotated with @Document annotation with indexName.